# Integer constants in PIC assembly: decimal vs. hex

Tags: assembly, hex, microcontroller, pic, microchip

I am doing programming in PIC based micro controller (microchip). The PIC model that I used is PIC16.

I have issue on classifying the data type

e.g. `MOVLW xxxx` where `xxxx` are the following:-

- `0x23`: hexadecimal
- `23`: decimal
- `D'20'`: 
  hexadecimal
- `1Bh`: hexadecimal
- `b'00101100'`: 
  binary

Why are `1Bh`, `D'20'`, `0x23` hexadecimal? Is there any other way to show hexadecimal in PIC assembly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0x23`
hexadecimal

`23`
hexadecimal

`D'20'`
decimal

`1Bh`
hexadecimal

`b'00101100'`
binary

This is the correct combination. In assembly, by default `23` is hexadecimal. D in `D'20'` indicates that the data type is decimal. Same to `1Bh` where h indicates hexadecimals.

Comment: To clarify further: Radix is hex by default. Modifier-less notation means 'shall assume radix'.

Comment: Slightly related, `'C'` will give the corresponding ASCII code for that character (`'C'` = `0x43`.)